# WinRT reason for disallowing custom generic types or interfaces

Tags: c#, generics, windows-runtime

After reading about WinRT a bit here and from Build decks, can someone shed light on the specific rationale that lead them to disallow us from passing our own IFoo<T>, yet they do it for their own sanctioned generic interface types?

WinRT must have a mechanism for describing, resolving and passing generic arguments, or some fancy facading around this for their own use.

I can't imagine "flattening" some of my C# class utility libraries in non-generic fashion, which I mainly want to use from C++ and not so much from JS.

I want first-class Intellisense and API support just as much as you do for your own MS types.

So ... why can't we use said mechanism too? Is this likely to be relaxed and allowed later or is this a permanent restriction? Or is this due to the language projection layers themselves custom-handling specific generic types without some WinRT-centralized meta-handling common to any generic type?

Thanks.

Comment: I think it's mostly because JS can't handle generic types at all. Collections work as JS arrays or objects, but general generic types wouldn't.

Comment: @svick Thanks, I was suspecting that might be the case. But it still begs the question of why MS-internal interfaces can be generic whereas we cannot produce them for WinRT comsumption.

Comment: Those interfaces have special handling when viewed from JS, which makes them work. But your custom types couldn't get the same special handling. What's more, how do you imagine other generic types would even work from JS? I don't think that's possible.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to pass a generic type that you create in C# over to WinRT APIs?

Comment: @iaimtomisbehave Specifically, I want to use WinRT as a "better COM and RCW mechanism than COM Interop" between some non-UI true native components and some managed ones. I don't really care to surface these to JS since it doesn't understand generics. But I still want to use my native/managed mixed component stack in my non-UI Metro app building portion. I guess I want an "anything but JS" component tag. Does that clarify?

Answer (score 9):

Under the covers, the types which are projected as IXxx are implemented by what are called "parameterized interfaces" or "pinterfaces".  Each language projection knows how to express the built-in parameterized interfaces in a natural and familiar fashion - for example, the IMap parameterized interface is projected by the CLR as IDictionary.

The language projections (especially JS) don't know what to do with custom parameterized interfaces, so they're not allowed.

There's no way of knowing if this restriction will be relaxed in the future, because there is no way of knowing what features will be added to Windows in the future.

Comment: Thanks Larry, the crux then is the decision to allow a public feature such as pinterfaces to only be supported in a subset of projections. In this case, allowing us to surface generic interfaces from C++ or C# components for integration, but not in JS. Or is this a runtime codegen issue as well, even in C++ or .NET?

Comment: All windows runtime features need to support all three language projections - we can't build low level windows runtime features for just two of the languages except for VERY restricted cases (for example, Xaml requires that we support unsealed classes and JS doesn't support that - thus unsealed classes are a C++ and CLR only feature).  The reality is that features can't be implemented for free and the teams building Windows 8 and the language projections have limited resources - we have to choose the set of features to implement carefully.

Answer (score 3):

Also for building component there are 2 advantages

- extension by composition is a better model for components ( remember you can still use interfaces for testing  ( eg a C# lib) they just cant be exposes as WinRT exportable components
- No polymorphic calls across the COM call boundary  since cant be inlined performance will be poor

I'm not sure JS would have limited this since JS cant create  objects anyway only consume they could have added another JS limitation - not framework interfaces are supported..