# What is the meaning of IOutputStream.FlushAsync's return value

Tags: windows-runtime

The [`IOutputStream.FlushAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.storage.streams.ioutputstream.flushasync) method returns an awaitable bool. The documentation for the return value says:

> The stream flush operation.

That seems, er, vague. Can someone shed some light on the details of what this really means? My current assumption is that it's a yes / no value indicating whether or not the flush worked, say, because the implementation doesn't support flushing.

Is that correct?  Most examples of this that I see simply await on FlushAsync and throw away the result. Should I be paying attention to the return value and handling it somehow, even if I know that the stream will be to a file on the file system?

Comment: Interesting, I can't see any reason for it - I'll crack open reflector and see what it does when I'm on a real pc.

Comment: That was my initial thought as well, but it seems like a lot of the code arounds this is internal. Everything I see seems to be internal to the runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just language friction, you can't declare an `IAsyncOperation<void>`.  The GetResults() method must return *something*.  You are only interested in Completed, you don't care about the fake return value.

Comment: Ah, WinRT doesn't let you have two interfaces that differ only by type parameters, does it? (Hence the lack of an `IAsyncOperation` with no type parameters)

Comment: Erm, not so sure.  Generic interfaces are an illusion created by the language projection, it doesn't exist in WinRT which is COM based.  I suspect the effort to handle *two* distinct interfaces in the projection wasn't worth the trouble.

Comment: OK, this sounds right given all the [restrictions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509099/winrt-reason-for-disallowing-custom-generic-types-or-interfaces) for generics in WinRT. I need to remember to throw out a lot of my .NET assumptions when dealing with RT...

Comment: Someone on the RT team just told me the same thing as this answer, so looks like that's that.

Comment: Huh? IAsyncAction exists and is the counterpart for IAsyncOperation without result value. So they *did* create two distinct interfaces after all. Really strange that they didn't use it here then.